# Limpar campos com Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Colegas.

Peguei um projeto do qual já consta o disparo de e-mails com PHP/Ajax, o disparo ocorre normalmente, porém os campos não são limpos após o disparo. Já tentei colocar form.value(); mas mesmo assim não funciona. Segue abaixo o código:

```
/* Contact form ajax Handler
    ================================================*/

    $(".ajax-form").on('submit', function() {
        var form = $(this);
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
            url: formURL,
            type: 'POST',
            data: postData,
            dataType: 'json',

            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

                if(data.success==1){

                    form.find(".alert").fadeOut();
                    form.find(".alert-success").html(data.message);
                    form.find(".alert-success").fadeIn(600);


                }else{

                    form.find(".alert").fadeOut();
                    form.find(".alert-danger").html(data.message);
                    form.find(".alert-danger").fadeIn(600);

                }
            },

            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)  { 

                console.log(errorThrown);
            }

        });


        return false;
     })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça assim, o comando para limpar o form no caso seria este

`$('.ajax-form')[0].reset();`

basta vc colocar na parte que deseja que execute esta função
no sei caso acredito que seja dentro do escopo do success

este comando tbm serviria

```
$(".ajax-form").trigger('reset');
```

Comment: Perfeito Jasar. Muito obrigado. Vou dar como aceitável sua resposta, porém tenho que aguardar 3 minutos.

Comment: da nada n ^^ q bom q ajudei